# Mouse scroll up not working in some applications

Tags: mouse, scrolling, mouse-scroll

Scroll up is not working in some applications such as Firefox, Zotero, and when I'm browsing "open folder/file" section in Atom/VS Code. In other environments (Konsole, Dolphine, Chromium-based browsers, etc.), it works flawlessly. Any idea how to fix this?

This issue has been around since when I upgraded 18.04 LTS to 19.04.

---

My current setup:

- OS: `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS x86_64`
- Mouse: `Logitech Gaming Mouse G600` (The same issue occurs when I'm using other mice so I assume this mouse is not the problem.

---

Here's what I found so far:

1. xev

- "ButtonRelease event" and "ButtonPress event" do not show up when I scroll up.
- Differences in mode (NotifyGrab vs. NotifyUngrab) and detail (NotifyVirtual vs. NotifyInferior)

**scroll up**

```
LeaveNotify event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0xd800001,
    root 0x6c9, subw 0xd800002, time 11818211, (27,58), root:(2935,585),
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyVirtual, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 18432

EnterNotify event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0xd800001,
    root 0x6c9, subw 0xd800002, time 11818211, (27,58), root:(2935,585),
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyVirtual, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 16384
```

**scroll down**

```
ButtonRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0xd800001,
    root 0x6c9, subw 0xd800002, time 11885441, (42,35), root:(4344,59),
    state 0x1000, button 5, same_screen YES

LeaveNotify event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0xd800001,
    root 0x6c9, subw 0x0, time 11885441, (42,35), root:(4344,59),
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyInferior, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 0

ButtonPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0xd800001,
    root 0x6c9, subw 0xd800002, time 11885529, (42,35), root:(4344,59),
    state 0x0, button 5, same_screen YES

EnterNotify event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0xd800001,
    root 0x6c9, subw 0x0, time 11885529, (42,35), root:(4344,59),
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyInferior, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 4096
```

2. xinput

- You can see that button4 (i.e., scroll up) is not turned off.

```
$ xinput get-button-map 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that this was due to the following lines in `~/.xbindkeysrc`.

```
"xte 'keydown Control_L' 'key t' 'keyup Control_L'"
b:4
```

The problem is solved after commenting these out.